# RollupError in vercel build for hosting vite + react website

Tags: reactjs, vercel

[Vercel Deploy Log of the build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pAR2o.png)

build is working in the local environment but when I push the build to Git Hub, vercel makes a build and fails with the above error shown in the image.
Repository link: https://github.com/Amanmawar17/Starman-projects

I want to know why the build in vercel is failing and why imports are working fine in the local environment.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.